# Why state redux-toolkit is proxy?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I need to change the values in a string that I have created. But I can't edit because TypeScript says I'm trying to put in state - void
**[Screenshot]**
[image]

After creating strings and substrings, they are all displayed in ReduxDevTools

**[Screenshot]**
[image]

But if you output state.levels to the console, it shows the prototype or something wrong ... not what you need to work
**[Screenshot]**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Redux Toolkit's `createReducer` API uses [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) internally automatically, the state in the reducer is a draft state, which is a proxy of the current state. See [Debugging and Inspecting Drafted State](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#debugging-and-inspecting-drafted-state)

> RTK re-exports `current`. You can use this in your reducers if you need to log or inspect the work-in-progress state.

```
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: todosAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    todoToggled(state, action) {
      // ❌ ERROR: logs the Proxy-wrapped data
      console.log(state)
      // ✅ CORRECT: logs a plain JS copy of the current data
      console.log(current(state))
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved problem myself - for editing array in my state i must use .splice